# Animating SVGs with CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have an SVG that was made in Illustrator - it's simply just an ellipse circle and a few lines. I'm trying to animate this using CSS - the animation I have in mine is simply just drawing each line out. But the below code is not working - is there an error with the CSS code or the SVG itself?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.cls-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
stroke: red;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 181.4 180.1"><defs><style>.cls-1{opacity:0.8;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{opacity:0.85;}</style></defs><title>test</title><g class="cls-1"><path class="cls-2" d="M29.43,27.43a115.34,115.34,0,0,1,14.43-11.1,96.91,96.91,0,0,1,10.93-5.95A93.61,93.61,0,0,1,67.51,5.62,96.77,96.77,0,0,1,81.14,2.78a92.13,92.13,0,0,1,13.43-.72,89.62,89.62,0,0,1,12.14,1.09,82.79,82.79,0,0,1,9.87,2.2c2.2.56,4.2,1.28,6.1,1.91.94.33,1.84.71,2.71,1s1.73.66,2.52,1c1.59.72,3.09,1.35,4.43,2.08s2.6,1.31,3.7,2c.94.55,1.09.65.59.36s-1.63-1-3.38-1.83a86.94,86.94,0,0,0-41-9.81,87.85,87.85,0,0,1,17,2A89.84,89.84,0,0,1,123,8.23a86.52,86.52,0,0,1,16.3,7.84,89,89,0,0,1,28.24,27.7,86.53,86.53,0,0,1,13.14,37,90.36,90.36,0,0,1,.05,20A83.84,83.84,0,0,1,176.23,120a87.78,87.78,0,0,0,.11-57.23A88.21,88.21,0,0,0,141,17.66c.9.56,1.73,1.22,2.57,1.82a87.45,87.45,0,0,1,34.22,49.29,83,83,0,0,1,2.07,10.34,90.51,90.51,0,0,0-2.07-10.34A78.94,78.94,0,0,0,173.24,56a90.9,90.9,0,0,0-6.81-12.38,87.8,87.8,0,0,0-12-14.82,94,94,0,0,0-10.82-9.35l-1.87-1.32-1.94-1.23c-.65-.4-1.28-.83-1.94-1.21l-2-1.13c-.79-.42-1.62-.89-2.51-1.3l.1.06A112.41,112.41,0,0,1,147,22.78a89.61,89.61,0,0,1,19.56,22.4,86.7,86.7,0,0,1,11.13,28.39,94.49,94.49,0,0,1,1.78,19.09,98.5,98.5,0,0,1-1,14.7,75,75,0,0,1-3.87,15.16c-1.3,3.54-2.84,6.32-4,9a21.68,21.68,0,0,1-1.31,2.9c-3.61,6.61-8.6,12.3-12.33,16.68a44,44,0,0,1-7.13,5.94l-2,1.4-1.77,1.13a11.25,11.25,0,0,0-1.87,1.34c-1,1.32-1.11,1.51-2,2-.43.25-1,.63-2.06,1.17s-2.41,1.42-4.5,2.51c-.51.26-1.5,1-2.67,1.67a33.9,33.9,0,0,1-3.54,1.91c-3.59,1.46-5.92,2.36-8.41,3.27-1.26.42-2.52,1-4,1.39l-2.47.73c-.89.26-1.88.47-3,.73a69.79,69.79,0,0,1-14.36,1.86c-1.93,0-3.81.09-5.94,0-1.07,0-2.21,0-3.44-.06s-2.58,0-4.05-.16a81,81,0,0,1-10.41-1.51c-4.71-1-9.13-2.46-9.13-2.46a93.15,93.15,0,0,1-16.8-8A62.67,62.67,0,0,1,34.72,155.9a72.91,72.91,0,0,1-14.3-16.43,95.29,95.29,0,0,1-9.61-20.27A70,70,0,0,1,7.3,103a84.63,84.63,0,0,1,0-15.17c.11-1.72.26-3.22.36-4.54s.33-2.44.52-3.43.44-2.68.66-4.57c.14-.93.33-1.91.51-2.86a21.62,21.62,0,0,1,.63-2.71l.06.9c.34-1.1.92-3.31,1.31-4.38s.38-.78.39-.48c0,.6,0,1.19.77-.65A94.81,94.81,0,0,1,18.41,52a90.84,90.84,0,0,1,7.4-12.4,4.33,4.33,0,0,1,.49-1.24c.79-1.19,1.71-2.27,2.57-3.41.34-.85-.08-.84.15-1.4-.64-.54,3-5.53,1.48-5a46.27,46.27,0,0,0-3.82,3.68l-2.83,3.07c-.88,1-1.72,2-2.39,2.69s.42-1.17.74-2.06c-.77,1-1.4,1.76-1.84,2.32a8.81,8.81,0,0,1-.91,1.06c-.35.31-.21-.14.29-1.09l-1.43,2,.38-1.21A91.57,91.57,0,0,0,8.34,56.44,74.27,74.27,0,0,0,2.71,75.82l-.33,2.33c-.09.86-.15,1.78-.23,2.72C2,82.73,2,84.64,1.93,86.16l-.15,3.15c-.06,1.18-.15,2.32-.13,2.94.32,2.13.63,1.81.94,2.7,0,2.34.14,5.37.49,8.56.13,1.61.45,3.23.68,4.86s.63,3.2.94,4.71c1.42,6,3.4,10.57,3.76,10.1l.91,2.4c.31.71.61,1.35.89,2,.57,1.2,1.06,2.23,1.64,3.22s1.11,2,1.8,3.18,1.46,2.52,2.49,4.17a89.75,89.75,0,0,0,10.3,13.72,90.9,90.9,0,0,0,14.23,12.69,95.75,95.75,0,0,0,18,10c1.16.53,2.36.92,3.51,1.37s2.29.83,3.42,1.18a91.72,91.72,0,0,0,35.74,4.12,89.82,89.82,0,0,0,32.23-8.88,88.66,88.66,0,0,0,26.57-20,87.15,87.15,0,0,0,18-30.41A90.92,90.92,0,0,0,149,21.27,90.39,90.39,0,0,0,119.17,5.45a93,93,0,0,0-30.11-4A92.23,92.23,0,0,0,63.61,6.06a91.72,91.72,0,0,0-18.29,8.48,84.57,84.57,0,0,0-10.77,7.69C32.75,23.87,31.1,25.67,29.43,27.43Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g><g class="cls-3"><path class="cls-2" d="M95.35,147.32l.07-1.18a1.83,1.83,0,0,1-.35.59C95,147,95.16,147.12,95.35,147.32Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M95.49,145.05v-.21l-.08-.18C95.45,144.79,95.47,144.92,95.49,145.05Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M95.28,143a3.35,3.35,0,0,0,0,1A2,2,0,0,0,95.28,143Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M95,144.62c.14-.12.29-.18.4,0h0L95.3,144A1.84,1.84,0,0,1,95,144.62Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M95,144.62c-.14.12-.27.31-.35.38A3.22,3.22,0,0,0,95,144.62Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M91.64,144.05c-.11-.21.85-.15.64-.56a10.84,10.84,0,0,1-.65-2.69c-.21-.42.86-1,.65-1.46-.25-1-1.5-3.44-1.47-2,.11,2.18.35,3.6.49,5.56.36,1.59.79,3.13,1.11,4.76A5.16,5.16,0,0,1,92.3,149c.15-.56.31-1.13.46-1.76C93,146.39,91.83,145.36,91.64,144.05Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M94.6,156l-.31-.62a3,3,0,0,0,.21-2.84L94,153c0,.55.31.62.53.13a5.73,5.73,0,0,0-.64,3.25C94.16,156.28,94.46,156.3,94.6,156Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M94,157l-.07-.64-.08,0,.12.64Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M94.47,138.62c0-2.73.09-5.3.22-7.81-.19-.2-.4-.34-.29-.6a1.8,1.8,0,0,0,.35-.58l.07-1.1-.07-.38h0c-.1-.21-.25-.15-.39,0a2.6,2.6,0,0,1-.36.38c.08-.07.22-.25.36-.38a1.84,1.84,0,0,0,.28-.58,3.07,3.07,0,0,1,0-1,2.1,2.1,0,0,1,0,1l.12.62.08.18.17-2.51c0-.19,0-.37-.07-.52-.12-.61-.25-1.21.22-1.58l0-.44-.09.08a1.14,1.14,0,0,1,.09-.16l.15-1.9a11.58,11.58,0,0,1-.53-1.26l.48-.42a1.25,1.25,0,0,1-.47-.71c-.29.34-.61.65-.81.94-.48.42.95,1,0,1.45.91-.49-.52-1,0-1.45.2-.29.52-.6.81-.94a2.37,2.37,0,0,1,.48-2,1.7,1.7,0,0,1-.48,2,1.25,1.25,0,0,0,.47.71l-.48.42a11.58,11.58,0,0,0,.53,1.26l.28-3.76c.69-8.21.63-15.78,1.1-24.3.29-4.62.7-9.06,1.25-13.41,1.11-8.69-.22-16.6,2.12-25.39.82-3.38.29-9.62.15-12.87-1.65-4.33-5.74-2-6-1.81-3.48,2.72-1.5,4.78-3.5,10.24,1.13-3.72,2.29,2.71-.09,6.22-3.62,5.09-.64,12.27-1.56,18.52-.23,1.56-.06,3.21-.13,5.08-1.23,9.66.3,18.64,0,28.8,0,2.69.86,5.06,1.33,7.33.15,1.66-.34,3.43-.35,4.77a23.84,23.84,0,0,0,.7,5.7c-.15-2-.39-3.38-.51-5.56,0-1.45,1.21,1,1.47,2,.21.41-.86,1-.65,1.46a10.45,10.45,0,0,0,.68,2.68c.21.41-.75.36-.65.56.2,1.31,1.42,2.34,1.14,3.17-.15.63-.3,1.21-.46,1.76a4.27,4.27,0,0,0-.07,1.08l.23.71a2.69,2.69,0,0,1,1-.3c-.06.34-.28.83-.33,1.17.05-.34.27-.83.33-1.17a2.69,2.69,0,0,0-1,.3c.54,1.73,1,3.73,1.4,5.59l.08,0a5.65,5.65,0,0,1,.63-3.25c-.22.49-.49.42-.53-.13l.48-.42a3,3,0,0,1-.19,2.84l.31.62c-.14.3-.44.28-.7.34,0,.21,0,.43.07.64A7.8,7.8,0,0,0,94.47,138.62Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M94.65,127.5c0,.15,0,.33.07.52l.16-2.1C94.41,126.29,94.53,126.89,94.65,127.5Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g><g class="cls-3"><path class="cls-2" d="M46.34,140.74l.56.06a1,1,0,0,1-.28-.35C46.5,140.34,46.43,140.55,46.34,140.74Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M47.42,140.86l.1,0,.08-.09Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M48.4,140.64a.72.72,0,0,0-.5,0A.48.48,0,0,0,48.4,140.64Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M47.62,140.39a.36.36,0,0,1,0,.4h0l.3-.12A.93.93,0,0,1,47.62,140.39Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M47.62,140.39a2.75,2.75,0,0,0-.18-.35A3.76,3.76,0,0,0,47.62,140.39Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M47.91,137c.1-.1.07.86.27.65.46-.26.86-.68,1.29-.67.2-.21.49.86.69.65.46-.26,1.66-1.52,1-1.48-1,.12-1.72.36-2.66.52-.77.36-1.5.8-2.28,1.13a1.26,1.26,0,0,1-.63-.11c.27.16.54.31.84.46S47.29,137.21,47.91,137Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M42.2,140.06l.29-.32c.43.7.89.44,1.36.19l-.2-.49c-.27.05-.3.32-.07.53a1.59,1.59,0,0,0-1.55-.61C42.06,139.62,42.05,139.92,42.2,140.06Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M41.73,139.43l.3-.07v-.08l-.3.13Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M50.49,139.81a34.28,34.28,0,0,1,3.73.2c.09-.19.16-.4.28-.29a1.07,1.07,0,0,0,.28.35l.52.06.19-.07h0a.36.36,0,0,0,0-.4,1.64,1.64,0,0,1-.18-.35c0,.08.12.21.18.35a.91.91,0,0,0,.27.28.72.72,0,0,1,.5,0,.48.48,0,0,1-.5,0c-.1,0-.19.08-.29.12l-.09.09,1.19.16a1.49,1.49,0,0,0,.25-.07c.29-.12.58-.24.75.23l.22,0,0-.08.08.09.9.14a7.34,7.34,0,0,1,.6-.53l.2.49a.77.77,0,0,1,.34-.47c-.15-.29-.3-.61-.43-.81-.19-.49-.47.95-.69,0,.22.91.5-.53.69,0,.13.2.28.52.43.81.29-.17.66,0,1,.49-.38.39-.68,0-1-.49a.77.77,0,0,0-.34.47l-.2-.49a7.34,7.34,0,0,0-.6.53l1.79.29c3.9.71,7.51.69,11.56,1.24a44.74,44.74,0,0,1,6.35,1.41c4.1,1.21,7.91,0,12,2.54,1.57.89,4.56.5,6.1.44,2.13-1.54,1.22-5.68,1.13-5.92-1.14-3.54-2.21-1.62-4.74-3.74,1.73,1.21-1.38,2.23-3-.22-2.3-3.72-5.86-.87-8.81-1.88a11.52,11.52,0,0,0-2.43-.21c-4.6-1.35-9,.09-13.81-.31-1.29,0-2.45.84-3.54,1.3-.8.15-1.64-.34-2.28-.36a6.11,6.11,0,0,0-2.74.7c.94-.15,1.62-.39,2.67-.51.69,0-.51,1.22-1,1.48-.2.21-.49-.86-.69-.65-.43,0-.83.41-1.3.67-.2.21-.16-.75-.26-.65-.63.21-1.13,1.43-1.53,1.15s-.57-.3-.83-.46a1.15,1.15,0,0,0-.52-.07l-.34.24a5.86,5.86,0,0,1,.14,1c-.17,0-.4-.27-.56-.33.16.06.39.28.56.33a5.86,5.86,0,0,0-.14-1,20.23,20.23,0,0,1-2.68,1.42v.08a1.59,1.59,0,0,1,1.55.61c-.23-.21-.2-.48.07-.53l.19.48c-.46.26-.93.52-1.35-.18l-.3.32c-.14-.14-.13-.44-.16-.7l-.31.07A4.67,4.67,0,0,0,50.49,139.81Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M55.8,140a1.49,1.49,0,0,1-.25.07l1,.15C56.38,139.72,56.09,139.84,55.8,140Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g><g class="cls-3"><path class="cls-2" d="M103.17,41l-.64,0a1,1,0,0,1,.34.33C103,41.43,103.08,41.21,103.17,41Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M101.94,41h-.11l-.09.09Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M100.85,41.28a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.07A.58.58,0,0,0,100.85,41.28Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M101.74,41.47c-.07-.14-.11-.29,0-.4h0l-.33.15A.88.88,0,0,1,101.74,41.47Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M101.74,41.47c.07.13.19.26.22.33A1.9,1.9,0,0,0,101.74,41.47Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M101.63,44.87c-.11.11-.13-.85-.34-.62-.5.29-.92.74-1.41.77-.21.22-.61-.82-.82-.6-.5.3-1.77,1.65-1,1.55,1.17-.2,1.92-.49,3-.72.84-.43,1.64-.92,2.5-1.31a1.55,1.55,0,0,1,.71.05c-.31-.13-.62-.26-1-.39S102.32,44.62,101.63,44.87Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M107.87,41.37l-.31.34c-.53-.67-1-.37-1.54-.08l.26.47c.29-.07.31-.34,0-.54a1.85,1.85,0,0,0,1.78.49C108.05,41.8,108,41.5,107.87,41.37Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M108.44,42a2.14,2.14,0,0,1-.34.09l0,.09.33-.16Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M98.55,42.27c-1.47.11-2.86.13-4.21.1-.1.19-.16.41-.3.31a1,1,0,0,0-.34-.33l-.59,0-.2.08h0c-.1.11-.06.26,0,.4a1.58,1.58,0,0,1,.22.33c0-.07-.15-.2-.22-.33a.88.88,0,0,0-.33-.26,1,1,0,0,1-.56.07.58.58,0,0,1,.56-.07c.11,0,.22-.1.33-.15l.09-.09-1.36-.07-.27.09c-.32.15-.64.29-.86-.16l-.24,0,0,.08-.1-.08-1-.08a6.93,6.93,0,0,1-.65.58l-.25-.47a.86.86,0,0,1-.36.5,8.81,8.81,0,0,0,.55.77c.25.47.46-1,.77-.09-.31-.89-.52.56-.77.09a8.81,8.81,0,0,1-.55-.77c-.31.19-.74,0-1.1-.41.4-.43.77-.06,1.1.41a.86.86,0,0,0,.36-.5l.25.47a6.93,6.93,0,0,0,.65-.58l-2-.14c-4.45-.4-8.52-.08-13.13-.27a63.46,63.46,0,0,1-7.29-.83C62,40,57.81,41.57,52.9,39.5c-1.88-.72-5.22,0-7,.26-2.21,1.78-.65,5.78-.52,6,1.72,3.39,2.68,1.35,5.75,3.18-2.07-1,1.3-2.37,3.35-.1,3,3.45,6.61.26,10,1a15.76,15.76,0,0,0,2.74,0c5.25.93,10-.89,15.46-.88,1.44-.09,2.67-1,3.87-1.59a11.71,11.71,0,0,1,2.58.18,7.56,7.56,0,0,0,3-.92c-1,.23-1.8.52-3,.72-.78.1.48-1.25,1-1.55.21-.22.61.82.82.6.48,0,.91-.48,1.41-.77.21-.23.23.73.34.62C93.49,46,94,44.71,94.44,45s.66.26,1,.39a1.14,1.14,0,0,0,.58,0l.37-.26a4.61,4.61,0,0,1-.22-1c.19,0,.46.24.65.29-.19,0-.46-.25-.65-.29a4.61,4.61,0,0,0,.22,1,23.2,23.2,0,0,1,2.93-1.62l0-.09a1.85,1.85,0,0,1-1.78-.49c.27.2.25.47,0,.54L97.19,43c.51-.29,1-.59,1.54.08l.31-.34c.17.13.18.43.23.68l.34-.09A4.7,4.7,0,0,0,98.55,42.27Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M92.57,42.53l.27-.09-1.14-.07C91.93,42.82,92.25,42.68,92.57,42.53Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g><g class="cls-3"><path class="cls-2" d="M154.14,149.94,153,148.67a3.16,3.16,0,0,1,.35.86C153.51,149.88,153.8,149.87,154.14,149.94Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M151.91,147.5l-.2-.23-.25-.13Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M149.66,145.52a6.82,6.82,0,0,0,1.08,1.07A4.21,4.21,0,0,0,149.66,145.52Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M151.14,147.39c0-.23,0-.4.31-.25h0l-.72-.55A2.85,2.85,0,0,1,151.14,147.39Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M151.14,147.39c0,.23.13.52.14.64A2.64,2.64,0,0,0,151.14,147.39Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M148.18,149.21c-.28-.14.46-.76-.11-1a20.39,20.39,0,0,1-3.22-2.31c-.57-.28-.46-1.69-1-2-1.17-.82-4.58-2.49-3.07-1,2.31,2.18,3.93,3.48,6,5.4,1.88,1.4,3.76,2.67,5.65,4.13a10.57,10.57,0,0,1,1.26,1.44c-.46-.69-.93-1.39-1.47-2.16C151.57,150.63,149.67,150.43,148.18,149.21Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M162.51,159.42l-.86-.42a6.07,6.07,0,0,0-2.76-3.07l.09.78c.59.53.85.41.51-.24a11.49,11.49,0,0,0,2.88,3.8C162.49,160,162.72,159.83,162.51,159.42Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M163.07,160.88l-.7-.61,0,.09.74.56Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M144.62,141.58c-2.79-2.82-5.36-5.54-7.83-8.23-.33-.07-.62-.06-.8-.41a3.11,3.11,0,0,0-.36-.85l-1.08-1.18-.45-.34h0c-.29-.14-.34,0-.31.26a2.68,2.68,0,0,1,.15.64c0-.13-.12-.41-.15-.64a3.2,3.2,0,0,0-.41-.8,7.22,7.22,0,0,1-1.11-1,3.87,3.87,0,0,1,1.11,1l.73.55.24.12L131.85,128c-.22-.18-.43-.34-.61-.47-.73-.52-1.45-1-1.54-1.73l-.47-.46,0,.14a1.1,1.1,0,0,1-.13-.23l-2-1.92c-.58-.25-1.19-.47-1.75-.76l-.17-.77a2,2,0,0,1-1.1-.28c.2.53.35,1.07.54,1.49.17.76,1.68.15,1.65,1.31,0-1.16-1.48-.55-1.65-1.31-.19-.42-.34-1-.54-1.49a4.73,4.73,0,0,1-1.92-2.22,3.3,3.3,0,0,1,1.92,2.22,2,2,0,0,0,1.1.28l.17.77c.56.29,1.17.51,1.75.76l-4-3.7c-2.2-2-4.28-4-6.26-6.05s-3.88-4.19-5.78-6.36c-3.79-4.33-7.51-8.88-11.89-13.46-4.69-5-9.5-9.42-14-13.9s-9-8.27-12.86-12.54a44.82,44.82,0,0,1-5.27-6.8c-.78-1.2-1.43-2.44-2.26-4a27,27,0,0,0-3.4-5,13.52,13.52,0,0,0-2.42-2,19.74,19.74,0,0,0-2.89-1.47l-2.18-.88a5.85,5.85,0,0,1-1.14-.59,8.08,8.08,0,0,1-2-1.95A19.93,19.93,0,0,1,49,41.89a6.78,6.78,0,0,0-2.61-2,2.57,2.57,0,0,0-2,.11,4.24,4.24,0,0,0-1.83,2,7.68,7.68,0,0,0,.68,6.52,21.47,21.47,0,0,0,2.45,3.64,20.94,20.94,0,0,0,2.05,2.11,24.4,24.4,0,0,0,2.81,2.09c-1.38-.85-1.77-1.45-1.42-1.51a8.51,8.51,0,0,1,2.48.56A9.27,9.27,0,0,1,54.94,57a5.33,5.33,0,0,1,1.63,3,15.27,15.27,0,0,0,2,5.65,23.41,23.41,0,0,0,2,3,30.8,30.8,0,0,0,2.44,2.82c3.45,3.66,7.51,6.8,10.7,10.22,1.6,1.71,3.59,3.18,5.63,5,5,5,10.17,9.16,14.91,13.6s9.37,9.59,14.54,15.27a43.72,43.72,0,0,0,9.05,6.69c2,1.48,3.69,3.47,5.15,4.7,2.3,1.92,4.33,3.35,6.41,4.8-2.11-1.82-3.7-2.94-6.14-4.82-1.62-1.28,1.9,0,3.08.69.58.23.54,1.62,1.1,1.86a24.42,24.42,0,0,0,3.23,2.13c.57.26-.16.89.12,1,1.48,1.16,3.38,1.35,4,2.41.54.76,1,1.46,1.48,2.15a8.65,8.65,0,0,0,1,1.16l.9.58a2.14,2.14,0,0,1,.4-1c.31.4.65,1.05,1,1.45-.32-.4-.66-1.05-1-1.45a2.14,2.14,0,0,0-.4,1c2.15,1.41,4.52,3.13,6.69,4.78l0-.09a11.41,11.41,0,0,1-2.89-3.8c.34.65.09.78-.51.24l-.08-.78a6.15,6.15,0,0,1,2.76,3.07l.85.42c.22.41,0,.61-.13.85.22.21.46.41.7.62A14.19,14.19,0,0,0,144.62,141.58Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M133.36,130c.18.13.38.3.6.49l-2.09-2.25C131.93,128.92,132.65,129.44,133.36,130Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g><g class="cls-3"><path class="cls-2" d="M143.18,45.06l-1.12,1.06a2.42,2.42,0,0,1,.79-.31C143.17,45.64,143.14,45.37,143.18,45.06Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M141,47.09l-.2.19-.1.22Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M139.33,49.16a5.42,5.42,0,0,0,.93-1A3.31,3.31,0,0,0,139.33,49.16Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M141,47.81c-.22,0-.38,0-.27-.3h0l-.47.67A2.75,2.75,0,0,1,141,47.81Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M141,47.81c.21,0,.48-.1.6-.11A3.16,3.16,0,0,0,141,47.81Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M142.93,50.68c-.11.26-.75-.46-1,.07a17.27,17.27,0,0,1-2,3c-.22.53-1.57.38-1.79.91-.69,1.09-2,4.27-.74,2.89,1.9-2.12,3-3.62,4.68-5.56,1.17-1.74,2.25-3.48,3.49-5.23a8.51,8.51,0,0,1,1.26-1.15c-.62.42-1.24.84-1.93,1.33C144,47.51,144,49.31,142.93,50.68Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M151.54,37.42l-.34.79a5,5,0,0,0-2.7,2.53l.73-.06c.47-.55.33-.8-.26-.49a9.3,9.3,0,0,0,3.39-2.62C152.11,37.45,151.91,37.23,151.54,37.42Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M152.88,36.93l-.52.64a.2.2,0,0,0,.08,0l.48-.69Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M136,53.82c-2.47,2.55-4.84,4.91-7.28,7.09-.05.3,0,.58-.35.73a2.79,2.79,0,0,0-.8.27l-1.08.91-.33.39h0c-.12.26,0,.32.25.32a2.6,2.6,0,0,1,.61-.07c-.13,0-.4.07-.61.07a2.79,2.79,0,0,0-.76.3,4.56,4.56,0,0,1-1,.9,3.43,3.43,0,0,1,1-.9l.52-.63.12-.22c-.84.69-1.69,1.35-2.55,2-.18.18-.35.34-.48.49-.53.58-1.08,1.16-1.74,1.08l-.48.33h.14l-.23.06-2,1.35c-.33.46-.64,1-1,1.4l-.73-.07a1.7,1.7,0,0,1-.47.92c.53,0,1,0,1.47-.06.73.06.43-1.5,1.49-1.16-1.06-.34-.76,1.22-1.49,1.16-.43.06-.94,0-1.47.06a3.88,3.88,0,0,1-2.38,1.16,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,2.38-1.16,1.7,1.7,0,0,0,.47-.92l.73.07c.36-.44.67-.94,1-1.4L114.75,71a47.22,47.22,0,0,0-12.17,10.5c-1.67,2.18-3,4.45-4.51,6.4a71,71,0,0,1-5.39,5.79,70.39,70.39,0,0,1-6.44,5.74,65.29,65.29,0,0,1-7,4.55,58.89,58.89,0,0,0-7.08,4.82c-2.22,1.76-4.3,3.61-6.35,5.45a94.53,94.53,0,0,1-13.05,10.42c-3.72,2.45-9.21,8.45-12.16,11.47-2.93,5.09,2,6,2.4,6,4.94.09,5.52-3.21,12-6.68-4.27,2.53,1-4.1,5.9-5.56,7.32-2,11.83-10.82,18.41-14.9,1.63-1,3.14-2.33,5.17-3.71a49,49,0,0,0,8.1-5.84,76.67,76.67,0,0,0,6.7-7c1-1.16,2.06-2.37,3.14-3.73a48.19,48.19,0,0,0,3.1-4.39c.91-1.46,1.69-2.8,2.46-3.92a21.78,21.78,0,0,1,2.62-3.12c2-2.16,3.7-4.62,5.69-6.73,1.57-1.39,3.71-2.33,5.15-3.37a32.23,32.23,0,0,0,5.64-5.27c-2,1.83-3.37,3.2-5.61,5-1.51,1.16.36-1.76,1.22-2.76.31-.49,1.64-.17,2-.68a14.85,14.85,0,0,0,2.38-2.83c.29-.52.86.25,1,0,1.21-1.34,1.36-3.15,2.34-3.72l2-1.31a7.22,7.22,0,0,0,1.06-1l.49-.83a2.44,2.44,0,0,1-1-.42c.35-.29,1-.59,1.31-.87-.36.28-1,.58-1.31.87a2.44,2.44,0,0,0,1,.42c1.21-2,2.65-4.2,4-6.21l-.08,0a9.28,9.28,0,0,1-3.39,2.61c.59-.3.73-.06.26.5l-.73,0a4.92,4.92,0,0,1,2.71-2.52l.33-.8c.37-.19.58,0,.82.16.18-.21.35-.43.53-.65A11.36,11.36,0,0,0,136,53.82Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/><path class="cls-2" d="M125.57,63.84c.12-.15.29-.32.46-.5-.71.56-1.43,1.12-2.16,1.65C124.54,65.05,125.06,64.45,125.57,63.84Z" transform="translate(-1.65 -1.43)"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: you are missing the stroke ... actualy they are invisible, you need to at least give them coloration  (ex: `stroke:red`)

Comment: @TemaniAfif ahh, perfect. Thanks man. But after trying `fill: red`, it doesn't have the same effect?

Comment: because you are amimating the stroke no the path

Comment: An example would be helpful @TemaniAfif